# DBeaver run AS400 CL commands

Tags: db2, odbc, ibm-midrange, dbeaver

I connect to an AS400 database using **DBeaver** and *ODBC*, it lets me run CRUD operations better than the *5250 Emulator*. Is there a way to run from DBeaver command lines like **WRKUSRPRF** or **CHGUSRPRF**?

Comment: Don't know AS400, but for LUW you have to run utilities outside of sql (load, reorg etc) as `CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('...')`. Perhaps there is something similar for AS400?

Comment: You are using dBeaver and ODBC to connect to DB2 for i? I would expect JDBC instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use commands that start with `WRK` without a 5250 session, some will run and produce a list of elements as a spooled file but many will just refuse to run.

You can run a command in any SQL client using QSYS2.QCMDEXC [stored procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=services-qcmdexc-procedure) or [function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=services-qcmdexc-scalar-function)

[IBM i Services](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=optimization-i-services) provide views, procedures and functions you can use to retrieve information about the system and make some changes (see [`CHANGE_USER_PROFILE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-change-user-profile-table-function))

If you use [IBM i Access - Client Solutions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions) maybe the "run SQL scripts" option is installed. It provides a `cl:<command>` syntax and can prompt statement

If what you want is more "modern" interface then you can use [IBM Navigator for i](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-navigator-i) depending on version and PTF installed on your server. Check `http://<your server>:2001`